# Atualizar chave em state quando outra chave for atualizada

Tags: javascript, react

A ideia principal baseia-se em um carrinho de compras, quando um produto é adicionado ao carrinho (chave `products`) a chave `orderTotal` é atualizada.

Dentro da chave `products` possuo um `object` com varios produtos que contem cada um o valor, e o total de produtos de compra: `ordered` e `price`, exemplo:

```
state = {
    products: {
        "a": {
            name: "A",
            price: 2
            ordered: 5
        },
        "b": {
            name: "B",
            price: 5,
            ordered: 2
        }
    },
    orderTotal: 0
}
```

Tentei colocar um `reduce()` dentro de `componentWillUpdate()`, porém não consigo usar `this.setState()` dentro de `componentWillUpdate()` pois isso gera um loop infinito.

```
componentWillUpdate () {
    const products = {...this.state.products};
    const orderTotal = Object.keys(products).reduce((sum, next) => {
        return sum + (products[next].ordered * parseFloat(products[next].price));
    }, 0);
    this.setState({ orderTotal }); // Loop infinito.
}
```

Preciso que toda vez que o `products` for atualizado, realizar um loop realizando o calculo de `ordered * price` e armazenar a soma de tudo em `orderTotal`, qual método posso utilizar?

Comment: O componente Carrinho recebe o objeto products via props?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo não, o state `orderTotal` fica somente no componente pai não é passado pra nenhum outro componente.

Comment: Mas e o objeto **products**? De onde ele vem?

Comment: Ele é iniciado vazio através do construtor, para o usuário adicionar produtos eu passo uma função para um componente filho que consegue adicionar outros objetos dentro de produtos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sobre setState

Como os dados são armazenados no `state` do `Carrinho`, então a melhor forma de ativar uma nova renderização é usando `setState` do `Carrinho`. Essa nova renderização será feita assim que possível, mas não imediatamente... é como se fosse um setTimeout passando 0.

***Importante:*** Isso quer dizer que o state não é alterado imediatamente após a chamada de setState.

Dito isso, existem duas alternativas para alterar o state, caso mais de uma alteração dependa do state anterior:

- alterar tudo de uma vez:

  ```
  setState({total: valorTotal, partes: valoresDasPartes })
  ```
- alterar usando callback:

  ```
  setState({partes: valoresDasPartes})
  setState((s,p) => {total: s.partes.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)})
  ```

A questão que resta é **onde se deve usar `setState`?**

- R: Dentro da callback que Carrinho passa para o filho.

### Exemplo

```
class Carrinho extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var listaProds = []
    for (var n = 1; n < 10; n++)
      listaProds.append(
        <Produto
          nome={"Produto "+n}
          adicionar={p => this.addProd(p, +1)}
          remover={  p => this.addProd(p, -1)}
          />)
     return (
       <div>
         <div>{listaProds}</div>
         <div>Total: {this.state.orderTotal}</div>
       </div>
       )
  }

  addProd(p, quant) {
    // adicionando o produto
    this.setState(function (state) {
        var s = {}
        s.products = state.products
        p = s.products[p.key] = s.products[p.key] || Object.assign({}, p, {ordered: 0})
        p.ordered = Math.max(p.ordered + quant, 0)
        return s
    });
    this.recalculaTotal()
  }

  recalculaTotal() {
    this.setState(function (state) {
        return {
            orderTotal: state.products
                             .map((p) => p.ordered * parseFloat(p.price))
                             .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Miguel acho que minha questão não ficou clara o suficiente, os componentes filho do "carrinho" não alteram o state, para facilitar o entendimento por favor veja [este link do arquivo no github](https://github.com/rafa-acioly/simple-store/blob/master/src/components/FrontStore/FrontStore.jsx), quando passo os produtos para os componentes filho eles só renderizam e para "alterar" essa prop eu passo uma função via prop para poder atualizar o state do componente pai.

Comment: Neste caso, fica valendo apenas o segundo ponto da minha resposta. Veja que dentro de `addProduct` eu chamo `recalculaTotal`.

Comment: entendi, é que o valor precisa ser recalculado diversas vezes, tanto quando é adicionado um produto quanto alteração de quantidade e etc.

Comment: Exato... eu falei sobre isso. Apaguei o primeiro ponto que não fazia sentido.

Comment: o `React` por sí só não possui nenhum método do tipo então? para realizar "watch" na alteração do state... ?

Comment: Acho que a proposta do React é essa... os caminhos que levam à alteração de um dado são lineares, previsíveis. Ao contrário do Angular por exemplo, que permite essas cascatas de eventos.

Comment: quando você passa a função `addProd` para o componente de `produto` na teoria teriamos que usar um `onChange` do lado do componente produto e chamar a função `addProd` com `this.props.adicionar()`? não entendi bem essa parte...

Comment: É isso... no meu exemplo o componente de produto chamaria this.props.adicionar passando como argumentos os dados do produto, ou this.props.remover pro caso contrário... lembrando que quando vc passa uma callback pra um componente vc tem que dar bind no this, ou usar a notação de lambda que já faz o bind automático.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly Conseguiu resolver? Ficou claro o que eu falei? Se não eu tento de outra forma. =)

Answer (score 1):

Na [documentação](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) oficial diz que o this.setState() não deve ser chamado dentro do `componentWillUpdate`, se deseja atualizar o state quando uma propriedade for modificada deve fazer isso dentro do método `componentWillReceiveProps`.

> componentWillUpdate() is invoked immediately before rendering when new
>   props or state are being received. Use this as an opportunity to
>   perform preparation before an update occurs. This method is not called
>   for the initial render.
>
> Note that you cannot call this.setState() here. If you need to update
>   state in response to a prop change, use componentWillReceiveProps()
>   instead.

Comment: O state atualizado é em um "componente pai", eu passo um objeto para um componente filho juntamente com uma função, logo, o que está sendo alterado é o state não uma prop.